# PHP 8 Session Problem with Object serialization

Tags: php, object, session, php-8

I am facing a very strange Session problem on PHP 8(even though it doesn't work with 7.4 also, but on 7.3 it works great).

What i do is i cerated a class where i set up the Export Object and store it on Session $_SESSION['AjaxExport'][sessionid]. Now i want to load this object stored by reference on the ifram which processes the export. When i session_start it fails to load the session at all.

```
AjaxExporter Class
private function ExportIntro(){
        
        while (ob_end_clean());

        // remove any old ajax exports
        unset($_SESSION['AjaxExport']);

        $rnd = rand(1, 99999);
        $this->sessionid = uniqid($rnd, true);

        $_SESSION['AjaxExport'][$this->sessionid] = &$this;
```

Above, loads the modal where the user gets a link to start the Export. by clicking on that link i load the Below function which loads the Object from Session and start exporting by auto-reloading to export in  process like (10%-20%...)

```
class NG_ADMIN_AJAXEXPORTER_CONTROLLER extends NG_ADMIN_BASE {
    public function Export()
    {

        $sessionid = '';

        if (!empty($_REQUEST['exportsess']) && isset($_SESSION['AjaxExport'][$_REQUEST['exportsess']])) {
            $sessionid = $_REQUEST['exportsess'];
        }
        else {
            return;
        }

        $exporter = &$_SESSION['AjaxExport'][$sessionid];
        $exporter->sessionid = $sessionid;
        $exporter->HandleToDo($_REQUEST['action']);
    }
}
```

When the process tries to start, i get no session at all.
session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed in...

Also tried to implement Seriazable on both classes but that not seam to work either because, even though the object is stored, there are no values in its properties so it's useless (even though i used reference &).

As i mentioned above, this code works just fine in php 7.3, the problems started since 7.4 and php 8

Comment: Do you have multiple requests running? if you're using PHP's default session handler the first request will lock the session file. ( I had an issue using custom session using MySql where a long request would overwrite a newer quicker request).
P.s. objects are always by reference so you don't need the "&" when assigning $this to the session

Comment: No, i am not running multiple requests. Also check this, something similar is happening, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79031

Answer (score 0):

So, finally figured this out.

As a friend told me that if a class has static properties serialization may not work and i was loading Twig v3 on parent class, so i destroyed all the properties that may contained the "template" property from Twig and it worked.

Generally, cleaned my object to only contain the necessary sub-objects that needed to complete my exports.